# CASE / CKP relearn without GM Tech II. 09 Chevy Malibu

Tags: chevrolet, malibu, computer, flash-programing, reprogram

I need to do a CASE Relearn procedure following a CPU swap on an '09 Chevy Malibu.

Is there a way I can do this without taking it to a GM dealer who has the Tech ii device? Are there lower cost devices, or a way to do it without a device. Or PM me if in the Atlanta area and can do it.

Note: Engine light code P0315 following ECU replacement indicates CASE relearn required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a scantool SnapOn/equivalent or a Tech2 to perform the relearn. AFAIK there is no way to do this without one.

Comment: Thanks Ben. From all the research I did, I could only find Tech2 or similarly priced devices to do it. I'll wait a bit to see if anyone else has any ideas.

Comment: @DylanCross If you need to do it only once I'd imagine a shop would charge you anywhere from free to an hour labor to do the procedure. It really only takes a few minutes to do if the car is fully warmed up.

Comment: If you can tell, I've been procrastinating. Calling shops today.